# Convert array of double's to array of longss such that relativity is retained

Tags: java, algorithm

Say I have an array of double's: `7.5, 10.0, 30.0`
I would want to convert to array of long's: `3, 4, 12`

That is the smallest whole number representation that retains the relation between the numbers.

In this case, each was multiplied by `2`, then divided by `5`.
Is there a generic algorithm to accomplish this?

Comment: Euclid's algorithm will get you some of the way, but floating point errors will cause it to be problematic.

Comment: I don't think your question follows standard guidelines of asking a minimal, reproducible example that shows what you have attempted so far. Please see the hlep section for asking good questions on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I guess some **lcm**s and **gcd**s can solve this problem.

The idea is to get the **lcm** of all elements, then multiply all elements by this **lcm** and take the integer **gcd** of all these new elements. Then, just divide each element by the **gcd** and print.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>    
using namespace std;

float mod(float a, float b){
    return a - b * floor(a / b);
}

float gcd(float a, float b){
    if(b == 0) return a;
    return gcd(b, mod(a, b));
}

float lcm(float a, float b){
    return (a * b) / gcd(a, b);
}

int intGcd(int a, int b){
    if(b == 0) return a;
    return gcd(b, a % b);
}


int main(){
    float v[3] = {7.5, 10.0, 30.0};

    float lcmAll = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        lcmAll = lcm(lcmAll, v[i]); 
    }

    int gcdAll = (int) round(lcmAll * v[0]);
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        v[i] = round(lcmAll * v[i]);
        gcdAll = intGcd(gcdAll, (int) v[i]); 
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        cout<<(int) (v[i] / gcdAll)<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

output: 3 4 12

Comment: There's no guarantee that multiplying all the elements by their LCM will give you integers.  For example, the LCM of 2.5, 3.5 and 4.5 is 157.5.  Multiplying through gives you 393.75, 551.25, 708.75.  Then what are you going to divide by?

Comment: you can add an integer with a lot of zeros behind, like `10000`, in the array.